# Eclipse Plugin for Tearout Panels Support

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, panel

Is there a plugin for Eclipse where I can tear panels out of the main window so I can view them on a separate monitor?

Visual Studio 2010 supports this feature natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this - Eclipse supports it by default.  You can do it with everything but the main editor window* (the Java text editor, for example).

Simply right-click on any view, then click "Detached".  From there, you can move it anywhere across your desktop - including additional monitors.

This will actually create a new floating panel / view group.  You can drag add or drag additional views into this same view group, if you'd prefer to have only one detached group to keep track of instead of many.

*If you want to open multiple editor windows, use Window / New Window.  This will produce a new window that includes a new main editor window, as well as a default set of views that can also be customized or detached, etc.  (I agree, it's not the most ideal, but it works for my needs.)  Additional details concerning this are available at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8886 - which seems to indicate that this has been further improved in 4.1 (not yet mainstream).

Comment: I just realized that but I want the main editor window to be torn out so I can have multiple files on both monitors.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty terrible. I hope supporting this is on the e4 roadmap. :/